# Strange Compilation Behavior

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I would like to say in advanced that I have not been able to recreate the problem I'm about to explain in just a few lines of code (believe me, I tried). And, that I've fixed the problem that I describe below. I'm just trying to determine why it happened.

I'm writing a [terminal code editor](http://www.github.com/taylorholberton/cedit)  for C. Upon testing it in another architecture (Arm, to be specific), I experienced a strange error - it no longer scrolled upwards (just downwards). I narrowed down the problem to this function call in this piece of code in `main`:

```
} else if ((c + 64) == 'V'){
    edit_scroll (&session, session.max_y / 2);
    session.cursor = session.disp;
    session.flags |= EDIT_FLAG_REPRINT;
} else if ((c + 64) == 'Y'){
    //here
    edit_scroll (&session, -1 * (session.max_y / 2)); /*
                                |                 |
        Removing parenthesis causes compilation errors
        in some platforms.
    */
    session.cursor = session.disp;
    session.flags |= EDIT_FLAG_REPRINT;
 }
```

`edit_scroll` will scroll upward when a negative value is passed to it (as shown). I fixed the error when I added those two parenthesis, and I figured out the expression was evaluating into `2147483598` within the function call. Note that the maximum of `int` in this compilation is `2,147,483,647` and the size of `session.max_y` was `100` when I ran this test (that variable represents the terminal height).

Here's the `edit_scroll` implementation:

```
int edit_scroll (struct edit * session, int deltay){
    // I printed deltay at this line, when I determined the value
    int i = session->disp;
    char * data = session->buffer.data;

    if (deltay > 0){
        for (; data[i] && deltay; i++){
            if (data[i] == '\n'){
                deltay--;
            }
        }

        if (!deltay){
            session->disp = i;
        }

    }

    if ((deltay < 0) && (session->disp > 0)){
        for (i--; i > 0; i--){
            if (data[i - 1] == '\n'){
                if (!(++deltay)){
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        session->disp = i;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Like I said, I haven't been able to reproduce this error in small test programs. I've tried this with Clang and Gcc and they both give the same error. Why does this evaluate to such an odd number? Is it safe to say that this is a compilation error?

```
-1 * session.max_y / 2
```

Would it help to show the assembly? Should I post more source code? I'm hesitant to post the entire code because the `.c` files alone amount to a little more than `1800` lines.

Comment: I don't think it's a compile error.  I think you were straying close to the limits of a signed int, and adding the parens brought the calculation back down to a better range.

Comment: ProTip: it's almost never a compiler error.

Comment: @H2CO3 yeah that's what I've heard. That's all I could think of though, since it only occurred when I compiled it differently. Oh well

Comment: @TaylorFlores I've once made a similar mistake in the GUI of an iOS app I was developing. I was surprised as to why the nicely animated menu items are moving in a strange curve on the left side of the screen but not on the right side. Fortunately, the day before I've done this, I **just** read a quiz on C integer operations and run into this problem explained. I've cast an unsinged integer to signed an whoa, problem solved!

Comment: @H2CO3 nice. I'm just surprised it's not a compiler warning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiplication and division are left-associative.  So if you remove the parentheses you are computing `(-1 * session.max_y) / 2` instead of `-1 * (session.max_y / 2)`.  If that max_y field is unsigned, then that division is going to do a sign extension in one case where it wouldn't in the other, and thus produce a different result.

Comment: Nitpick - signed division is a different operation from unsigned division. They don't differ by a sign extension.

Comment: Metanitpic: signed and unsigned division by a constant 2 are shift operations that differ only by a sign extension bit. :)  But yes: general division is indeed a different machine instruction for unsigned logic.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the value of `max_y`, if it is unsigned, then when you multiply it by `-1` the `-1` is converted to `unsigned` before the multiplication happens, and then the result is `unsigned`.

I recommend casting away the unsignedness before you do anything involving a negative number. Even if you weren't doing division, you can end up with integral overflow and undefined behavior when converting a very large unsigned result (which is supposed to be a negative number) back to the signed type. (I suspect such overflow is the source of the compilation errors you saw, since otherwise everything is well-defined, just in the wrong way.)